# oop php create a class that can produce different objects w

Tags: laravel, oop

I use laravel.I want to create a class Frequest,which can produce an F21request ,F22request,F23request etc.These objects will have common attributes and each one can have different attributes also maybe with traits , which is the best solution , thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is a lot of clever ways of doing your question, please come with some code so we have something to work with, what is a straight non optimized way this could be implemented?